# What does the -e do in a bash shebang?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

egrep "^username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null 
if[ $? -eq 0 ] 
then 
  echo "doesn't exist" 
fi
```

This script will not run without the -e. What does the `-e` do for this script?  Also, what does the `$?` do in this context?

Comment: Odd. No `-e` in the man page (I really want to see an answer address this). `$?` contains the last exit code (that of the `egrep` process spawned above).

Comment: @pst: `-e` is documented under `set`.

Comment: You could simplify your script by doing this: `if egrep -q "^username" /etc/passwd ; then echo "doesn't exist" ; fi`

Comment: You're missing a space between `if` and `[`. This script won't work *with* `-e`, because if `grep` doesn't find anything then under `-e` the script will terminate right there. Without `-e`, you've got the message backwards: a status (`$?`) of 0 means that grep did find the user. Note that this should be `grep '^username:', by the way (what if there's another user with a longer name?).

Comment: Will `#/bin/bash -e` have the same effect as `#/bin/bash` on line #1 and `set -e` on line #2 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The way to use \`/usr/bin/env sed -f \` in shebang?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14887/the-way-to-use-usr-bin-env-sed-f-in-shebang)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your post actually contains 2 questions.

1. The `-e` flag instructs the script to exit on error. [More flags](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Modifying-Shell-Behavior)

   If there is an error it will exit right away.
2. The `$?` is the exit status of the last command. In Linux an exit status of `0` means that the command was successful. Any other status would mean an error occurred.

To apply these answers to your script:

```
egrep "^username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
```

would look for the `username` in the `/etc/passwd` file.

- If it finds it then the exit status `$?` will be equal to `0`.
- If it doesn't find it the exit status will be something else (not `0`). Here, you will want to execute the `echo "doesn't exist"` part of the code.

**Unfortunately** there is an error in your script, and you would execute that code **if the user exists** - change the line to

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
```

to get the logic right.

**However** if the user doesn't exist, `egrep` will return an error code, and due to the `-e` option the shell will immediately exit after that line, so you would never reach that part of the code.

Comment: In addition, you can make the script work correctly without the -e by replacing the first two lines with `if egrep "^username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null`.

Comment: Why is no `set` required though? :-/

Comment: @pst: Because the `-e` is given to bash as a command-line argument. All options listed under *`set`* are also accepted by bash in its command line – note the first sentence in section *Options* of the manual page.

Answer (score 19):

All the bash command line switches are documented in `man bash`.

```
      -e      Exit  immediately  if a pipeline (which may consist of a
              single simple command),  a subshell command enclosed  in
              parentheses,  or one of the commands executed as part of
              a command list enclosed by  braces  (see  SHELL  GRAMMAR
              above) exits with a non-zero status.  The shell does not
              exit if the command that fails is part  of  the  command
              list  immediately  following  a  while or until keyword,
              part of the test  following  the  if  or  elif  reserved
              words,  part  of any command executed in a && or || list
              except the command following the final  &&  or  ||,  any
              command  in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's
              return value is being inverted with !.  A trap  on  ERR,
              if set, is executed before the shell exits.  This option
              applies to the shell environment and each subshell envi-
              ronment  separately  (see  COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT
              above), and may cause subshells to exit before executing
              all the commands in the subshell.
```

Comment: Ahh. I looked for it in the man, but after finding -e in the file tests and no -e under the main arguments I gave up. Nice excerpt. Why is no `set` required though? :-/

Answer (score 2):

Your script is incorrect, because

```
egrep "^username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null 
if[ $? -eq 0 ] 
then 
  #echo "doesn't exist" # WRONG
  echo "the USER EXISTS"
fi
```

exit status 0 - mean - everything is OK, in the case of grep mean "OK, found the string".
exit status != 0 mean something is wrong, in the case of grep 1 mean, "not found", 2 mean "can't open input"...